# Convert input to output Object

Tags: javascript

i'm working with object
i want to write function convert input to output, can u guys help me?

```
 data = {
 members: [
{
  id: 1,
  name: "John",
  job: 1,
},
{ id: 2, 
  name: "Sarah", 
  job: 2 },
 ],
job: [
 { id: 1, name: "Developer" },
 { id: 2, name: "Junior" },
 { id: 3, name: "Senior" },
 ],
```

};

output:

```
result =  [
{
id: 1,
name: "John",
job: Developer,
},
{ id: 2, 
name: "Sarah", 
job: Junior },]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `map` method to update each property and `find` to find job name via `id`

```js
    const data = {
     members: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "John",
      job: 1,
    },
    { id: 2, 
      name: "Sarah", 
      job: 2 },
     ],
    job: [
     { id: 1, name: "Developer" },
     { id: 2, name: "Junior" },
     { id: 3, name: "Senior" },
     ],
    };

    const res = data.members.map(el => ({...el, job: data.job.find(i => i.id === el.job)?.name}));
    console.log(res)
```

Comment: It had a mistake, I thought it was an oversight. You were comparing the user ID instead of the job ID.

Comment: yes, you were right, its was typo